# Auto scan without click on scan button

Tags: android, camera, java.util.scanner

I have searched many libraries but didn't find anyone in which auto scan happens.
I have to click on scan button to take pic. What I need is without pressing any button app should scan the document by itself.

There is an app on play store. I need the same as this did.

[Genius scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thegrizzlylabs.geniusscan.free&hl=en)

Following are the libraries through which I have gone through.

[Github 1](https://github.com/ctodobom/OpenNoteScanner)

[Github 2](https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo)

Comment: So what is problem in second library? You just need to call intent whenever you want to scan document.

Comment: I have to click on a button to take photo of image and then it crops the image. But I just need like a Qr code scanner. It just scan the code automatically and move to next screen.

Comment: Ok... I got your problem now.

Comment: Do you have any solution ?

Comment: Yeah.. May be... There is a fragment class in scanlibrary called ScanFragment. Try to add scanButton.performClick(); after init() call in onCreateView().

Comment: Can you please tell me the library which contains ScanFragment ?:

Comment: In second library you mentioned, you have to include scanlibrary, that library is having ScanFragent.

Comment: I didn't find ScanFragment in that library.

Comment: Go to this path AndroidScannerDemo/ScanDemoExample/scanlibrary/src/main/java/com/scanlibrary/